# Soc Emulation in QEMU

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux, qemu

I am trying to learn SoC level emulation by going through the source code.I am not sure about all the steps required to do Soc Emulation.

I think first would be the CPU emulation and the rest of would be peripheral emulation.

Now for a particular CPU emulation what are all the steps?

First step would be to intialize CPU and I see there specific function defined in QEMU for the same,

https://github.com/sheepdog/qemu/blob/master/hw/arm/highbank.c

```
cpu_arm_init(cpu_model);
```

This QEMU specific call will initialize arm based CPU'S.

But would anyone let me know what others step needed in CPU initialization?

Comment: Take a look at `a9mp_priv_initfn` in https://github.com/sheepdog/qemu/blob/master/hw/cpu/a9mpcore.c. There you will see that is initialize the interrupt controller (GIC) then the SCU and then some timers. Then in `a9mp_priv_realize` it connects all these components, and for some adds a memory mapping.